# Rails by Example Tutorial Request Examples and Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

In the Rails on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl, the Request Examples make assertions on the response.  I installed the cabybara and steak gem to create acceptance tests.  After installing capybara, the requests examples are configured to use capybara.  capybara examples have a different syntax and don't recognize the response.
How do I reset the Request Examples to run as RSpec example?

Test Error:

```
4) Users signup failure should not make a new user  
    Failure/Error: click_button  
    wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)  
    # ./spec/requests/users_spec.rb:13  
    # ./spec/requests/users_spec.rb:7
```

Request Example

```
describe "failure" do  
    it "should not make a new user" do  
        lambda do  
            visit signup_path  
            fill_in "Name", :with => ""  
            fill_in "Email", :with => ""  
            fill_in "Password", :with => ""  
            fill_in "Confirmation", :with => ""  
            click_button  
            response.should render_template('users/new')  
        end.should_not change(User, :count)  
    end
end
```

Comment: Please show us some code or errors.

Answer (score 0):

This might have something to do with rspec-rails request_example_group.rb.

[request_example_group.rb](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/bb14e3514ea9ea62b9fa5d55dd6be4769c966b66/lib/rspec/rails/example/request_example_group.rb)

If the capybara lines are commented out, then the Request Examples are not defaulted to capybara.

```
capybara do
   include Capybara
end
```

In the Acceptance examples, include capybara.

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/acceptance_helper')

feature "This Is My First Feature", %q{
    In order to ...
    As a ...
    I want to ...
} do

    include Capybara
    scenario "Scenario name" do
        visit signup_path
        fill_in "Name", :with => ""
        fill_in "Email", :with => ""
        fill_in "Password", :with => ""
        fill_in "Confirmation", :with => ""
        click_button "Sign up"
        page.has_content?('welcome to the sample app')
    end
end
```

I ended up forking rspec-rails and commenting out the capybara lines.
In the Gemfile, the gem installed from the fork.

Why bother?  We want both white box and black box testing.

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly point out in your answer, rspec-rails will `include Capybara` if it is installed.  I think they're assuming that it never hurts to `include` Capybara, just in case you need it.  Is that a problem for you?  In other words, what specifically is the Capybara DSL conflicting with?

(This might be also be worth bringing up on the [RSpec mailing list](http://rubyforge.org/mailman/listinfo/rspec-users).)

As for the error you posted, it seems that you are simply missing an argument to the [`click_button`](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions#click_button-instance_method) method.